Pod Player Quality Change Issue
I have added Pod Player Plugin as dependency for playing youtube live videos in my flutter app.I am not satisfied with youtube player and iframe plugin, because of I used Pod player.I am satisfied with all features other than its quality change option on it. When tapping quality change option it always shows 360p only.But its documentation shows that we can change the quality upto 1080p.
I tried several ways to correct it.

    playerController = PodPlayerController(
      playVideoFrom: PlayVideoFrom.youtube('A3ltMaM6noM', live: false),
      podPlayerConfig: const PodPlayerConfig(
          autoPlay: true,
          isLooping: false,
          videoQualityPriority: [1080, 720, 360]),
    )..initialise();


I have changed the videoQualityPriority option with several quality option like above,But no result(always shows 360p)

Image1
Image2

I have tried by changing video format with live and non-live Youtube video urls, but this also not effective

full code,
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pod_player/pod_player.dart';

class PodPlayerScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  PodPlayerScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late PodPlayerController playerController;

    playerController = PodPlayerController(
      playVideoFrom: PlayVideoFrom.youtube('A3ltMaM6noM', live: false),
      podPlayerConfig: const PodPlayerConfig(
          autoPlay: true,
          isLooping: false,
          videoQualityPriority: [1080, 720, 360]),
    )..initialise();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: PodVideoPlayer(
          controller: playerController,
          podPlayerLabels: const PodPlayerLabels(
            play: "Play label customized",
            pause: "Pause label customized",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Please any one help me to acheive this. Advancely Sorry for my bad english
nb:Is there any alternative for PodPlayer with better features(otherthan Splayer, beacuse i tried that, it not has quality change option) please suggest me.

flutter & dart -> latest version,


Pod Player Plugin -> 0.2.2,


Testing app-> Real device, Android 14


Use splayer: ^1.0.29
PodPlayerConfig({
    bool tap = true, 
    bool autoPlay = true, 
    bool isLooping = false, 
    bool forcedVideoFocus = false, 
    bool wakelockEnabled = true, 
    bool isLive = false, 
    List<int> videoQualityPriority = const [1080, 720, 360]
})


Can you specify the complete name of the dependency to be added?

Use this player instead: ModernPlayer.
It is working fine like this:
 ModernPlayer.createPlayer(
      video: ModernPlayerVideo.youtubeWithUrl(
      url: lessonVideoController.videoLink,
      fetchQualities: true),

... and you can edit the rest of the control here.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
